# How to get tooltip the function definition of an imported function, in vs code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I' m using vscode as my main IDE for js development.
I noticed that there is the possibility, for **vscode**, to show a tooltip of the **structure** of the imported function **(as i show in the screenshot)**.

So far, i can achieve that only on my created custom functions, and not on the functions that are imported from **node_modules**.

For example, when i hover the mouse over **createSelector** i want to get the tooltip of the definition of that function.

Should i install a specific extension or is there a settings that i need to enable ?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: holding down the ctrl key and mouse hovering will help you handle this, it works for me.

Comment: do you get that tooltip (above), when you hover + ctrl(or command) ?
for me it does not work for functions that come from `node_modules` ?